# Не работает appendChild для конкретного элемента

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая небольшая структура. Пытаюсь li добавить child div, но не выходит. Если заменить dot.appendChi.. на любой другой, например document.body, всё работает
В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: @Sergey, заставлять кого-то пытаться разобраться в ваших проблемах по скриншоту - не очень затея. Текст можно скопировать и выполнить, а переписывать код со скриншота никто не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно. Как Вы думаете, что присходит в строке, где назначается `innerHTML`?

```
dot.innerHTML = i + 1;
```

Все, что к этому моменту находилось внутри `dot`, будет уничтожено.